# How to display my uploaded image (Document) to Page Layout and Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

Have problem with this. I am able to upload image file to document. But how can I display this to page layout and to a visualforce page.

Page Layout:

[image]

I want to put the image below the Logo label..
and also how to display it in vf page.

This is the image in document. 
[image]

this is the link: this is the file id : 0X9000000A6bH2...
Hope you all understand me.. thanks

Comment: if the answer is helpful to you, can you please mark it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

A sample Visual Force page along with the custom controller. For this example, I have stored an image in the Document object with name"sample pic". You can add this VF page to layout of the page.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ImageController" showheader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form>
      <apex:image url="{!imageURL}">
    </apex:image></apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class ImageController {
 public String imageURL{get;set;}

  public ImageController()
  {
    imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
    List< document > documentList=[select name from document where 
                                    Name='SamplePic'];

    if(documentList.size()>0)
    {
      imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
    }
  }
}
```

> Update

**VF Page**

Here is a working solution with custom Event object with a Logo field. I assume the URL is `https://<your salesforce URL>/apex/logodisplay?id=a0Li000000L03KU`. Where the `a0Li000000L03KU` is a event id.

```
<apex:page standardController="Event__c" extensions="ImageController" showheader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form >
      <apex:inputHidden id="eventLogo" value="{!Event__c.Logo__c}" />
      <apex:image url="{!imageURL}"></apex:image>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller**

public with sharing class ImageController {

```
public String imageURL{get;set;}
private Event__c eventObject;

public ImageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    eventObject = (Event__c)controller.getRecord();
    imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
    String logo_name = eventObject.Logo__c;
    List< document > documentList=[select name from document where Name=:logo_name];

    if(documentList.size()>0)
    {
      imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi sir, how can i make that 'SamplePic' become dymanic?.. i mean i need to pass a value from visualforce page to this ImageController.. how can I do that?.. thanks..

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo What value you need to pass? Is it image name? How do you get that value in VF page?

Comment: yes the image name.. i get that from my Event object.. i have a field there named Logo.. where i save the name of the image.. <apex:form >
        <apex:inputHidden id="eventLogo" value="{!Event__c.Logo__c}" />
        </apex:form>

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo In that case, upload all event logos in Salesforce and provide them a unique name like `event_a_logo`. Assign the logo name to a variable say `logo_name`, and pass the name to the  Soql query dynamically as `List< document > documentList=[select name from document where Name= :logo_name ];`

Comment: how would i assign it sir?..

Comment: public String eventlogo{get;set;}

I did this but its not working.. no return

Comment: @LennonLeopoldo Please find the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ImageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    eventObject = (Event__c)controller.getRecord();
    imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
    String logo_name = eventObject.Logo__c;
    List< document > documentList=[select name from document where Name=:logo_name];

    if(documentList.size()>0)
    {
      imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
    }
    else{
      imageURL = '';
    }
}
```

Add else condition to update imageURL so that in case if there are no document on that record (in my case I used attachment images) than a broken image/link will not be displayed.